# Localstack 503 Service Unavailable - Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, docker, localstack

I have localstack running, either via docker-compose or docker command. Service starts up

**Docker Compose File**

version: '2.1'

```
services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "4566-4599:4566-4599"
      - "${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}:${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=${SERVICES- }
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG- }
      - DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR- }
      - PORT_WEB_UI=${PORT_WEB_UI- }
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR- }
      - KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY=${KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - HOST_TMP_FOLDER=${TMPDIR}
      - DEBUG=1
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

**Log**

```
    .
    .
    .    
    Running on 0.0.0.0:4583 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
        Running on 0.0.0.0:4587 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
        Running on 0.0.0.0:4585 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
        Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
        2020-08-14T14:57:39:INFO:botocore.credentials: Found credentials in environment variables.
        Ready.
```

When I run a command such as `aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4568 kinesis list-streams` on powershell/command-prompt etc it throws this error:

```
An error occurred (503) when calling the ListStreams operation (reached max retries: 4): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1>
<p>The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems. Please try again later.</p>
</body></html>
```

But if I use WSL Ubuntu 18.04 running on my machine, It will give the correct output of:

```
{
    "StreamNames": []
}
```

VERSIONS:

- localstack: 0.11.3.3
- awscli: aws-cli/1.18.119 Python/3.8.5 Windows/10 botocore/1.17.42

**Is there some setup I'm missing for windows to talk to endpoints?**

Comment: I'm betting that docker socket sharing is what is not working properly on Windows. That used to be a Linux-only feature.

Comment: I've made some changes from this post: https://gist.github.com/robfe/9a858b59f4d394ef5deb2517833e75c6 (also mentions the docker socket sharing). Still no luck.

This does however work fine on a pc with Windows 10 Home (latest build), so seems like Windows has fixed it at some point. My laptop I can't update though